# Refresh element in a div ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a small web application that manages some lessons and reports the statistics for them (completed and not completed). When one clicks on the `.finish` button, I would like to refresh the statistics `div` of the lessons.

Here is the `php` file:

```
 <?php
    include_once('config_mysql.php');
    $data = new MysqlClass();
    $data->connect();
    $sql = "select * from Lessons";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    <div class="history">
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     <div>
      <h2>name: <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
      <h2>completed: <?php echo $row['completed']; ?>
     </div>
    }
   </div>
    ?>
```

And the event handler attached to the `.finish` class:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.finish').click(function(event){
        completeLesson();
         $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "statistic.php",
                    success: function(html){

                    }
        });  
    }
}
```

I did not include the `completeLesson()` function (which also makes an AJAX call) because it is not important.

I would like to refresh the statistics of lessons without refreshing the page. I tried to refresh it with an AJAX call but it did not update the data. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: `<php` sb `<?php`

Comment: You also need to close `php` tags when inserting direct HTML. And you need to do something with the result.

Comment: you also need to do something with `html` you get in `success: function(html)`. insert it into dom, append, anything.

Comment: I was wrong in writing, the statistics.php file works,but it is not updated, is only for information,the problem is the ajax call ,

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions. They've been deprecated for over 2 years now. Considder using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead in combination with [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have atleast 2 problems.

First, you need to do something with the variable `html` in your `success` callback.

Second, since `completeLesson` makes its own ajax call, you have to wait for that call to return before you put in your call to statistic.php. if you don't wait, there's a chance that the second Ajax call will be completed before the first and it won't bring in the new data.

One solution would be to pass `completeLesson` the second Ajax call as a callback function.

```
function completeLesson ( /* your other arguments */, callback) {
    // this would be the Ajax call already in completeLesson
    $.ajax ( {
        // whatever arguments you use for the ajax call
        success: function (data) {
            // the code you had in here before...
            // after all that code add these 2 lines
            if (callback)
                callback();
        }
    });
}
```

And now, you change the event listener for finish to (assuming statistic.php is echo'd out between `<div id="result"><?php include 'statistic.php'; ?></div>` and also that you've added `id="#hs"` to the `.history` div):

```
$('.finish').click(function(event) {
    completeLesson(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "statistic.php",
            success: function(html) {
                $('#hs').remove();
                $('#result').prepend(html);
            }
        });
    });  
}
```

You may want to use [`$('#result').append(html)`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).

Comment: thank you now update the statics, but i have 2 div after the refresh, one updated and the other not, i give a identier at the parent but non remove the div not updated

Comment: <div id="result">
<div class="history" id="hs">
and 
  var historyParent = $('#result').parent()
                historyParent.find ('#hs').remove();
                historyParent.prepend(html);

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear but your change will actually make the solution simpler. 1 minute and I'll update.

Comment: @Andrea485 see update. Also, see here for documentation on `.html()` http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: what do you mean 2 div?

Comment: @NewbeeDev what do *you* mean "2 div"?

Comment: $('#result').html(html); it's work, but i have a button in result and after the refresh is no longer clickable ie there are no more events

Comment: @Andrea485 wasn't aware of the button. see the latest edit